# Error Handling in Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, exception

I have a Ruby method that iterates through a loop (`loop_a`) and calls another function (`do_something`) each time through the loop. I want Ruby to go to the next cycle of `loop_a` even if it has the function `do_something` throws an error. I am using the exception handling code below but the application continues to stop on the error. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
loop_a.each do |str1|
  do_something(str1)
  rescue Exception => e
    Logger.error 'An error occurred: #{e}"
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have a `begin`, `rescue`, & `end`. You also opened with a single-quote and closed with a double-quote.

```
loop_a.each do |str1|
  begin
    do_something(str1)
  rescue Exception => e
    Logger.error "An error occurred: #{e}"
  end
end
```

You may wish to read more on [exception handling in Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_exceptions.html).

Comment: To extend this a bit more, you can use a bare `rescue`, without the normally associated `begin`, if you're in a method definition. That might be where part of the confusion occurred.